# EF Core & Azure SQL with Managed Identity (no `IDBAuthTokenService`)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL Database deployed to Azure App Services. Essentially I'm trying to do what is described in [this question][1] from January 2019, but `IDBAuthTokenService` does not exist in `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` (if it ever did, there are no references anywhere).

- What is the right way to do this now?
- Should I ditch `DbContext` and create a ConnectionFactory myself instead? (I've seen a colleague do this, but using `DbContext` seems like the idiomatic way to do it in EF Core).

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //code ignored for simplicity
    services.AddDbContext<MyCustomDBContext>();

    services.AddTransient<IDBAuthTokenService, AzureSqlAuthTokenService>();
}
```

**MyCustomDBContext.cs**

```
public partial class MyCustomDBContext : DbContext
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IDBAuthTokenService authTokenService { get; set; }

    public MyCustomDbContext(IConfiguration configuration, IDBAuthTokenService tokenService, DbContextOptions<MyCustomDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        authTokenService = tokenService;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection");
        connection.AccessToken = authTokenService.GetToken().Result;

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
    }
}
```

**AzureSqlAuthTokenService.cs**

```
public class AzureSqlAuthTokenService : IDBAuthTokenService
{
    public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        AzureServiceTokenProvider provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var token = await provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");

        return token;
    }
}
```

[[EF Core Connection to Azure SQL with Managed Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187241/ef-core-connection-to-azure-sql-with-managed-identity?rq=1][1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication**

[image]

---

---

In **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSingleton<AzureServiceTokenProvider>(new AzureServiceTokenProvider());
services.AddDbContext<SqlDBContext>();
```

---

In your **DbContext.cs** :

```
private AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider;
public SqlDBContext(DbContextOptions<SqlDBContext> options, AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider) : base(options)
{
    this.azureServiceTokenProvider = azureServiceTokenProvider;
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:jackdemo.database.windows.net,1433; Initial Catalog=jackdemo; "; 
    connection.AccessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
}
```

Comment: Beware, Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication has been deprecated recently. Be sure to watch the next developments at MSFT when using this library.