# Managed Identity Sql Auth with EF Core - Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-identity

I have a dotnet 5 (isolated) Azure Function app that needs to access an Azure Sql Server database via EF Core 5. I would like to use the managed identity of the function app when making the sql server requests.

### What I tried

I followed the instructions [here](https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2021/03/10/managed-identity-azure-sql-entity-framework/).

I created a new AD account called "smsrouterdb" and made this the Azure Sql Admin.
The name of my function app is "func-smsrouter-msdn-01". So after logging into the DB via SSMS as "smsrouterdb", I created a contained user as below:

```
CREATE USER [func-smsrouter-msdn-01] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [func-smsrouter-msdn-01]
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [func-smsrouter-msdn-01]
```

I then triggered my function app via an http request.

### What happened

I got the following error from the function app:

> One or more errors occurred. (Invalid value for key 'authentication'.) ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'authentication'. at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilderUtil.ConvertToAuthenticationType(String keyword, Object value)

I realised that this was because an old version of the nuget package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient was being referenced. So, I explicitly added a reference to v3.0.0.

I then got the following error

> Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

However, if I change the connection string's authentication property to "Active Directory Interactive" and promote the object id of the managed identity for the function app to be Sql Admin using the following command:

```
az sql server ad-admin create --resource-group <tg name> --server-name <server name> --display-name MSIAzureAdmin --object-id "id of managed identity here"
```

then the rows are written correctly. My concern is that the managed identity should not need to be a sql admin.

### Config

The nuget packages of the project containing the dbcontext are:

```
"Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.1"
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.6"
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.6"
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.6"
"WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
```

From the main Azure Function project, I have references to the following nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 3.0.0
Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.6.0
```

The only code in my db context is:

```c#
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            logger.LogInformation($"SqlSvrConString=[{sharedConfig[ConfigConstants.SqlSvrConnString]}]");
            connection.ConnectionString = sharedConfig[ConfigConstants.SqlSvrConnString];
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
        }
```

My connection string is:

> Server=servernamehere.database.windows.net;Initial
> Catalog=dbnamehere;Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;

Can anyone explain why this fails unless the managed identity is made sql admin?

Comment: In Azure SQL database, we can not directly set service principal as Azure SQL AD admin.  Azure does not support it. If we want to do that, we need to add the sp as the meneber of AD group then set the group as admin. Besides, we also can set the sp database contained user. For more details, please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview#azure-ad-features-and-limitations and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities.

Comment: Hi Jim, a managed identity object can be set as an Azure Sql Admin - that's what I did with the azure cli command at the top of the post. What my question is about is why this would be necessary

Comment: You can set the sp as a database user according to your need:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities. But before doing that, we also need to set ad amin.

Comment: That's the problem. If the sql ad admin is set to anything other than the object id of the managed identity then I get the issue described in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root cause of the problem was that when I'd issued the command: CREATE USER [function name here] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER, although the function name was spelled correctly, the case was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to work around these kind of errors is to use the guid of the functions identity instead of the name. This works as well.

```
CREATE USER [abcdef-1234-5678-ghijkl] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```